# Trying to split data with spaces into two different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split my data which has numbers that are separated by 1 or more number of spaces into two different columns. It has name called DUT0 and I want to seperate it into two columns with names "Temperature" and "Voltage".

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re as r
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
file = pd.read_table('sample.txt')
print(file)
file[['vtg', 'temp']] = file['DUT0'].str.split('\s+-\s+', expand=True)
print(file)
```

I keep getting this error: "Columns must be same length as key"

The data has numbers with 1/more spaces in between the two numbers. I just want to separate the 2 numbers into 2 columns to make a list of the second column.

The text looks like this:

```
DUT0

5600    2.3

5650   12.9

5700  23891
```

There are different number of white spaces in between these two numbers.

Expected output :

Temp    Vtg

```
5600 2.3

5650 12.9

5700 23891
```

Comment: Can you copy paste part of the text in your question please?

Comment: Just `.split()`? `"123    4432".split()`

Comment: Try printing the right hand side of your equal sign to see if the data is what you expect.

Comment: You should include some first lines of `file['DUT0']`, and expected output.

Comment: ```file[['vtg', 'temp']] = file['DUT0'].str.split(expand=True)```
I tried this and it makes three columns, DUT0 with both data, Temp and Voltage

Comment: Even though the above change works, it makes the elements type as str and not int. So i cannot do int operations on these elements anymore.

Comment: @Frank i tried that. It gives me an error "'Series' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: I just tried your code by removing the regex, it works fine: `file[['vtg', 'temp']] = file['DUT0'].str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: Hi @Frank, it does but I get a list of strings instead of int values. I need to work on these int values later. What I did was just map all the values to int. I was looking for a way to directly get a list of int values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read_table` specifying the `sep` as a regular expression:

```
file = pd.read_table('sample.txt',
                     sep='\s+',
                     engine='python',
                     skiprows=1,
                     header=None,
                     names=['vtg', 'temp'])
file.head()

#   vtg     temp
# 0 5600    2.3
# 1 5650    12.9
# 2 5700    23891.0
```